# Fulltext search query not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to run a fulltext index search in CodeIgniter.

My search function looks like this:

```
public function get_searchresult_count($searchresult)
{
    $today_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $db_photos = $this->load->database('photos', TRUE);
    $db_photos->select('*');
    $db_photos->from('photos');
    $db_photos->where('MATCH (`title`, `description`) AGAINST ("'.$searchresult.'")', NULL);
    $db_photos->where('approved', '1');
    return $db_photos->count_all_results();
}
```

I need the return to be `count_all_results` because it needs to get a number for the pagination of the results.

I can't get it working, I get this error:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AGAINST ("lime") AND `approved` = '1'' at line 3
>
> SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM (`photos`) WHERE `MATCH` (`title`,
>   `description`) AGAINST ("lime") AND `approved` = '1'

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that the query works on the mysql cli or phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the third parameter of the `where()` function to false to prevent automatic escaping of your parameters. Otherwise the quotes in your match clause are escaped and create an invalid query.

Taken verbatim from the AR manual page

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to >FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the selection query and return the result. After your 'where' clause, trying adding:

```
$query = $db_photos->get();
return $query->count_all_results();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: In the latest CodeIgniter query doesn't have a count_all_results() method